# Understanding common parameters to MPI_Send in C

Tags: c, mpi

I am learning MPI and in the send functions my instructor gives us to review,  there is a parameter that I do not understand. I understand the what is happening within  the MPI function.  I am not familiar with the syntax and need some clarification.

The parameter

> (my_rank + 1) % comm_sz

is the destination of the receiving message `my_rank + 1` but what does the `% comm_size` do?.

```
MPI_Send(Greeting, strlen(Greeting) + 1, MPI_CHAR, (my_rank + 1) % comm_sz, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
```

Comment: `%` is the modulus operator. It gives the remainder if you divided `(my_rank + 1) / comm_sz` but without altering `myrank`.

Comment: got it. forgot about integer division.

Comment: It creates a circular topology where each rank sends to its right neighbour. Basically, the modulo operation closes the circle by having the first rank (0) be the right neighbour of the last rank. For the left rank it would be `(my_rank - 1 + comm_sz) % comm_sz`.

Comment: I agree with @HristoIliev. Maybe you could create an answer for that?